# Errors with first child element in draggable/droppable/sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

Currently creating a drag and drop playlist function for my website, and have the following code to drag and drop videos into a Playlist container:

```
var transferred = false;
$( "#videoResultsDiv li" ).draggable({

  connectToSortable: '#Playlist',
  helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        if(!transferred)
            $(this).show();

        else
        {
            $(this).remove();
            transferred = false;
        }
    }
});


    $("#Playlist").droppable({
  tolerance: 'touch',
drop:function(event, ui) {
  ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));

  $(this).sortable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
receive: function (event, ui) {
  transferred = true;
}});
}});
```

This works fine for most of the videos in the `Playlist` container, but the first video to be dropped into the container carries over styling and functionality from `videoResultsDiv`, causing various errors, including duplication. I've tried various permutations of `var transferred`, changing `connectToSortable` to `appendTo` (the current configuration is the only one I found that lets me drag videos from the `videoResultsDiv` into the outside `Playlist` container), and removing the `ui.helper` clone, but all cause some issue or another.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was to get rid of the droppable code, as per this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xD2dW/12/

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui)
    {
        transferred = true;
    }
});
```